# Are there psychological traits that predict that a person will be good at acting?

Tags: emotion, learning

I'd like to know if there are psychological traits that predict that a person will be good at acting. And, if psychology can say something about this , which aspects of acting can mostly be taught and which one are hard to be (being dependent mostly some sort of 'natural aptitude').